# If $g$ is a non-decreasing function and $X$ a random variable, does this imply that $P(X > x) \leq P(g(X) \geq g(x))$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If $g$ is a non-decreasing function, why do we have that for a random variable $X$:

$$ 
P(X > x) \leq P(g(X) \geq g(x))
$$
?

My intuition is the following, is it correct?

I believe that this is because:

$$
\{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega) > x\} \subseteq \{\omega\in \Omega: g(X(\omega)) \geq g(x)\}
$$

It seems that whatever $\omega \in \Omega$ that "cause": $X(\omega) >x$, should be less than the $\omega \in \Omega$ that "cause": $g(X(\omega)) \geq g(x)$,

**because if $g$ were constant for all or some parts of the $x$ space**, then it can be the case that for an $\omega \in \Omega$ where $X(\omega) \leq x$, we have that $g(X(\omega)) \geq g(x)$, in which case we found an

$$
\omega' \notin \{\omega\in \Omega: X(\omega) > x\} \ \ \text{such that} \ \ \omega' \in \{\omega\in \Omega: g(X(\omega)) \geq g(x)\} 
$$

Is this the correct proof or thinking? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details about $g$.  In particular, what is the codomain of $g$?

Comment: Things look good (although for a proof, more details would be helpful): If $y\geq x$, then $g(y)\geq g(x)$.  Therefore, the set of $y$'s that satisfy the first inequality also satisfy the second inequality.  Then the claim follows from the fact that measures are monotonic.

Comment: I read this somewhere and did not see anything specific mentioned about $g$, is there something I should have there? thanks!